# Change Query Source depending on Cell Value

Tags: google-sheets

I use cell values on a sheet to change what values a query will be looking for. Is there a way to change what *sheet* the query is using as a source depending on the value of a cell?

This is the query I currently use. For example, if I type something in the cell C4, the query will only return values that contain whatever I typed in C4.

```
=Query(Input!A:AD,"select * where C contains """&C4&""" AND D contains """&D4&""" AND E contains """&E4&""" AND F contains """&F4&""" AND G contains """&G4&""" AND H contains """&H4&""" ORDER BY A desc",2)
```

I now want to have this same concept, but change Input!A:AD to whatever I type in cell A4. A4 could contain "Input", but if I change A4 to "Archive", I would like it to "read"

```
=Query(Archive!A:AD,"select * where C contains """&C4&""" AND D contains """&D4&""" AND E contains """&E4&""" AND F contains """&F4&""" AND G contains """&G4&""" AND H contains """&H4&""" ORDER BY A desc",2)
```

I've tried similar wildcards like &A4& and """&A4&""" in place of the sheet name, but this returns errors. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with the following formula, adapting it to their needs:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(C2); "SELECT *")
```

Here's an example:
[image]

Comment: Indirect was the key. There were a few tricks though. This is what ended up working.

    =Query(Indirect(concatenate(A1,"!A:B")), "select * where Col1 contains 2")

The query can no longer call columns by letters, so Col1 etc have to be used.